# Move data from MS Word to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a Microsoft Word document with 400 multiple choice test questions. I need to put all this text into a Microsoft Excel chart and I thought it would be alot easier if I was able to have a macro that allowed me to select all text that began with `a.` and ends the section at the first paragraph object after `a.`.

I tried getting help and was told to use the below macro but the macro does not do anything. I just want the macro to select all the text only. If I were to do this in Microsoft Word manually, I would hold down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and highlight all the text that begins with `a.` and ends at the first paragraph object.

```
 Sub Aselection()
'
' Aselection Macro
'

Dim pgh As Paragraph
For Each pgh In ThisDocument.Paragraphs
With pgh
If Left(.Range.Text, 2) = "a." And Left(Right(.Range.Text, 3), 2) = "a." Then
Debug.Print .Range.Text
End If
End With
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I am not familiar with VBA for Word, but this will only print the found text in the Immediate Window (`Debug.Print .Range.Text`), which you can open by pressing `CTRL+G` while in the Visual Basic Editor. So you need to replace that line by something that will select the text or whatever you need to do.

Comment: @user1437779: assylias is right. One option would be to store the found text in an array and then finally export it to Excel.

Answer (score 1):

`ThisDocument` typically refers to the template document containing the executing code.
Use `ActiveDocument` instead.

Also as @assylias said in his comment, `Debug.Print` is only for code debugging purposes.
Replace that entire line with `.Range.Select`.

**This should work:**

```
Sub Aselection()

    Dim o As Object
    Dim pgh As Paragraph

    Set o = CreateObject("excel.application")
    o.workbooks.Open ("E:\Aashay Data\Projects\Excel\Carton\Screen Printing.xlsx")
    o.ActiveWorkbook.worksheets.Add.Name = "x"
    o.ActiveWorkbook.worksheets("x").Activate


    For Each pgh In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        With o.ActiveWorkbook.worksheets("x")
            Debug.Print pgh.Range.Text
            If Left(pgh.Range.Text, 2) = "a." And Left(Right(pgh.Range.Text, 3), 2) = "a." Then
                .Cells(i, 2).Value = pgh.Range.Text
                i = i + 1
            End If
        End With
    Next
    o.Quit

End Sub
```

EDIT: After reviewing this and testing a lorem ipsum text, I realised that Word VBA does not allow you to select multiple discontinuous segments (See MS Support article [KB288424](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/288424/n) for more). 
   I suppose the easiest way then is to simply export to excel where the debug.print is and I have edited my code accordingly.

Comment: Another option would be to append each 'a' line to a text file, so instead of having to select all 'a' lines, you would just find them one by one and then append them to a text file.  Once you reach the end of the document, you could do whatever you need to with the information in the text file (and depending on what you need to do, this might be easier than introducing Excel into the mix).

Comment: @rryanp: I was going to do that but it was just as easy to simply throw it out to Excel as the OP wanted. So I just put up the Excel code.